# PHP Arrays - getting sum of hours per month for certain job

Tags: php, arrays

I would appreciate some help with php arrays. I need to create a graph, but I can't seem to get the values from database the way I would like them to. 
So basically what I need are hours per month for certain job.
Database looks something like this:

```
Date       |   Job   | Hours
2012-01-01 |  104    |   8.5
```

Every job has a different number, but I hope this helps a little.

I need to get the sum of hours per month spent on one job.
So far, I have made an array for months and looped through them:

```
 $month_date_array = array('01', '02', '03', '04', '05', '06', '07', '08', '09', '10', '11', '12');
 foreach ($month_date_array as $month) {
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM database WHERE date LIKE '%-$month-%'";
 $result = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
      $job[] = $row['job'];
    }
}
```

Okei, I made some changes and I am going to update my question:
The year does matter, it can't group 2011 and 2012 together. The year comes from a dropdown menu - the user chooses what year. 
Next I added an array of jobs, because I just figured out that I can't take all jobs, so the job array looks something like this:

```
$job = array('22', '6', '12', '55');
```

Basically I would like to know how to get the sum of hours what somebody spent on doing one job per month. And I don't want to do it with SQL, I need arrays of some sort, because later I have to put together a graph.

Comment: First, you shouldn't use the mysql_* functions as they have been depreciated. Second, what does the 8,5 stand for in the hours column?

Comment: What are column formats ("8,5" does not look like a numeric)? Use `SUM()` function too

Comment: @SamHuckaby in a lot of countries a comma is used to indicate decimals and a point for a thousands seperator: 1,000.00 = 1.000,00

Comment: @SamHuckaby 8 to 5 working hours, perhaps? You need to tell us what you want on your axes.

Comment: Sidenote: You cannot have a column name by date. Its a mysql reserved keyword.

Comment: @doublesharp yes, to represent data - not to store it.

Comment: But i agree, a column definition would be good just in case it's a mixup of types and formats.

Comment: @doublesharp I realize this, I just wanted to be sure that is what the OP intended it for before I made the assumption. :)

Comment: Also, your `LIKE` fails because it picks up dates and fragments of years too.

Comment: @AbhishekSaha Yes you can; have you tried? `Date` is in the "permitted keywords that don't need backtick-escaping" list. Read up on it [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html)

Comment: @newfurniturey, appologize for my ignorance and my wrong comment. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to learn how to manipulate and do this with arrays:

```
<?php
$jobs = array();
$month_date_array = array('01', '02', '03', '04', '05', '06', '07', '08', '09', '10', '11', '12');
foreach ($month_date_array as $month) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM database WHERE date LIKE '%-$month-%'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
        $jobs[$row['job']][$month] += $row['hours'];
    }
}
```

But know that this is actually going to group all the years together. In other words November 2011, 2012 and 2013 will be added together if those dates exist.

You could also do this grouping and adding with SQL only.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/416d9/5/0

```
# Group by Month and Year
SELECT YEAR(`Date`) as `Year`, MONTH(`Date`) AS `Month`, `Job`, SUM(`Hours`)
FROM `your_table`
GROUP BY `Year`, `Month`, `Job`
```

or http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/416d9/6/0

```
# Group by Month combining the Years
SELECT MONTH(`Date`) AS `Month`, `Job`, SUM(`Hours`)
FROM `your_table`
GROUP BY `Month`, `Job`
```

Comment: Sql queries did not work out for me, I don't know why, but they did not give any values back.. I tried multiple times with different values, but nothing. And I would still like to do them with arrays, but I made some changes: I added an array of jobs too, so maybe you can help me with that.

Comment: I made some changes and I got it to work, thanks a lot, sorry for the wrong comment before :)

Answer (score 1):

Rather inefficient, when you could have

```
SELECT month(date) AS month, COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM database
GROUP BY month(date);
```

one single query doing everything your query loop is doing, and with far less overhead.

Comment: this groups results of */05/2012 with */05/2013 for example

Comment: `group by year(date), month(date)` blah blah. OP didn't mention anything about years, just months.

Comment: Yea, sorry I forgot to mention it at first, I edited the question, because the year is important.

Answer (score 1):

I disagree with most of the other answers as they group also same months from other years. Something like this would be more efficient.

```
SELECT CAST(DATE_FORMAT(`Date`, '%Y-%m-01') AS DATE) month, SUM(`Hours`) hours
FROM `your_table`
WHERE `Job` = 104
GROUP BY month
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8cf63/1

This technique will "round" your date to the first day of the month; thus, if you GROUP on those dates, you are grouping on months. This is nice because it combines the year and month together into one column for easy sorting and comparing and joining, if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You must chance sql query like that:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM database WHERE MONTH(date) = '".$month."'";
 $result = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
      $job[] = $row['job'];
    }
```

Comment: this groups results of */05/2012 with */05/2013 for example

Comment: It does not matter, because it finds values right now, but i just don't now how to sum them all together the right way.

Answer (score 0):

How about the below query:

```
SELECT SUM(hours) FROM database 
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(date,'%m' ) = $month
GROUP BY  DATE_FORMAT(date,'%m' );
```